# updating list values of dictionary with the values of another dictionary and printing the result as the values of first dictionary in python

Tags: python

I have two dictionaries :

First one is legenddict :

```
legenddict = [ 'Standard_Animator: blue, 3f7fff, 00bfff, 3fffbf, green, bfff3f, ffbf00, ff7f00, red' ,
               'Extended_Animator:    LightGray, blue,3f7fff,00bfff,3fffbf,green,bfff3f,ffbf00,ff7f00,red, Magenta' ]
```

and second one is colordict :

```
colordict = ['blue' : 'ff00ff', 'red' = '808080', 'lightgray':'d3d3d3','magneta':'00ff00']
```

I wanna print all values of legenddict to be compared with the keys of colordict it should produce output as colors with all hexadecimal digits

Comment: Are those lists or dictionaries? What you show is not correct Python syntax. Can you please correct the syntax and also the formatting of the question (using the [edit] link)? It is hard to answer right now.

Comment: Also, you should include your attempt and how it fails rather than just asking for a solution to be provided.

Answer (score 2):

Well, first off your syntax for defining literal dictionaries is incorrect.  Dictionaries are surrounded by curly brackets like this: `{}` instead of square brackets like this: `[]`  If you want `'Standard_Animator'` and `'Extended_Animator'` to be keys for lists of colors, you would want to do something like this:

```
legenddict = {"Standard_Animator" : ["blue", 3f7fff, 00bfff, 3fffbf, "green", bfff3f, ffbf00, ff7f00, "red"], 
              "Extended_Animator" : ["lightgray", "blue", 3f7fff, 00bfff, 3fffbf, "green",  bfff3f, ffbf00, ff7f00, "red", "magenta"}

colordict = {'blue':'ff00ff', 'red':'808080', 'lightgray':'d3d3d3', 'magenta':'00ff00'}
```

So, to print the values in legenddict using the color names in colordict, you can check to see if the colors are keys in colordict, and if so, look up the values:

```
for color in legenddict['Standard_Animator']:
    if color in colordict:
        print colordict[color]
    else:
        print color


for color in legenddict['Extended_Animator']:
    if color in colordict:
        print colordict[color]
    else:
        print color
```

Comment: But I am not getting output what I need it is going to an infinite loop

Comment: what I expect the output is 9 Colors defined in Legend: STANDARD_ANIMATOR
     ff00ff
     3F7FFF
     00BFFF
     3FFFBF
     888888
     BFFF3F
     FFBF00
     FF7F00
     808080

Comment: I expect the output to be in the format STANDARD_ANIMATOR : ff00ff,3f7fff00,bfff, 3fffbf, ff44ff, bfff3f, ffbf00, ff7f00, '808080'   i.e all colornames should be replaced by their hexcode that is read from colordict

Comment: I think you misunderstand the purpose of this site.  It's to help you figure out your own solutions to programming problems, not to write your code for you.

Comment: yes I know that I have already written the code but not having much knowlegde of python b'coz I am vnew this language...just I didn't found the solution to this problem in book or whatever site thatz why I dumped this question even this is only for my knowledge not for any coding